# list of masked functions in R

Tags: r, duplicates, package, mask

I use a lot of packages and I know some functions are masked because they exist in several different packages.
Is there a way to get the list of duplicate functions (or masked functions?)

The ideal would be to have a list of duplicate function and for each of them, the list of packages in which it exists.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

in R base:

```
 conflicts(detail=TRUE)
```

And to find the list of environments that contain a version of

```
getAnywhere(x = "functionA")
```

Note: `getAnywhere` also finds the functions which are **not** exported. and that are hence not creating conflicts.

A better (simpler) result could be obtained using:

```
x = "functionA"
names(which(sapply(search(), FUN = function(env) exists(x, env, inherits = FALSE, mode = "function"))))
```

Comment: well. it is showing functionA from package P interacts with something. But how I find the package Q that is interacting?

Comment: I think there is a base function to do that but cannot find it back. In the mean time I suggest simply the code above.

Comment: ok the function I was looking for is `getAnywhere`. I edited the answer

Comment: dang pesky lag command is everywhere.  dplyr does it best!

Comment: @thistleknot, thanks for this comment; I was just about to decide NOT to use lag in a dplyr chain (and use Lag from Hmisc package which then masks "summarise" from dplyr).  Your comment prompted me to try dplyr::lag which fixed my problem.