# Error in .External2(C_dataviewer, x, title) : unable to start data viewer

Tags: r, dataframe, display

In R I get the following errors any time I hit `View()` or `data.frame` and I do not understand why. It happened suddenly.

```
> View(Fhat_all)
Error in .External2(C_dataviewer, x, title) : unable to start data viewer
In addition: Warning message:
In View(Fhat_all) : unable to open display

> da <- data.frame(comb[true_comb_RMSE[1],1], comb[true_comb_RMSE[1],2],
comb[true_comb_KS[1],1],comb[true_comb_KS[1],2])
Error in (function (env, objName)  : 
could not find function "object.size"
```

I checked this other page in Stackoverflow [Can't use either View() or edit() functions, getting "Error in .External2(C_dataviewer, x, title) : invalid device" error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009308/cant-use-either-view-or-edit-functions-getting-error-in-external2c-data) but I didn't understand how to fix it. So I hit `locale` on terminal and got this result:

```
Last login: Mon Mar 21 16:47:07 on ttys000
MacBook-Pro:~ "username"$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
MacBook-Pro:~ "username"$ LC_CTYPE = C R
-bash: LC_CTYPE: command not found
```

so I hit `LC_CTYPE=C R` on the the terminal as by suggestion and tried to view a vector in `R`, but I got the same error message:

```
> View(w)
Error in .External2(C_dataviewer, x, title) : unable to start data viewer
In addition: Warning message:
In View(w) : unable to open display
```

Can you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009308/cant-use-either-view-or-edit-functions-getting-error-in-external2c-data) work for you?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I opened XQuartz and then the View() function worked.

Answer (score 2):

Experienced this after updating some packages.

Restart R worked for me (in RStudio: Ctrl+Shift+F10). After that, the error vanished and `View` worked well again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when using the `jagsUI` package, which masks the `View` function. Perhaps you have conflicts between packages?

Check potential conflicts between functions by calling `conflicts(detail=TRUE)` (Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354697/list-of-masked-functions-in-r) for finding which functions are masked in R).

Easiest workaround in my case was calling `detach("package:jagsUI", unload = TRUE)` once I finished using JAGS.

Comment: Don't post same answer on multi pal post.Flagged as duplicate if you think.

Comment: @Shree I think they are different questions, and neither flagged as duplicate. I came across this question first, resolved my problem and thought to offer a potential solution. I only found the second question later. I think my answer might be helpful for other SO users if they only find one of these. I also note other posters offering the same suggestions on both.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the view(), then it will work!