# How to predict values of a model using the results of a non-linear regression

Tags: r, prediction, predict, non-linear-regression, nonlinear-functions

I have the following equation:

`t ~ a1 * log(X/X0) + a2 * log((Xmax - X)/(Xmax - X0))`

I used the package `minpack.lm` with the data frame of experimental data below, to perform a non-linear regression(`nlsLM`), and obtained the values of `X0`, `Xmax`, `a1` and `a2`.

```
t   X
0   2.42254
5   2.64426
10  3.34135
20  5.16827
30  6.34615
40  7.45192
55  7.25962
70  8.43750
```

```
    a1         a2         X0       Xmax 
  3.132196 -34.323302   2.060305   9.547698
```

Now I would like to use the same model to predict the values of `X`, for `t` ranging from 0 to 70. When using `predict()`, I get only `t` values.

Since it is not possible to isolate `X` from the equation, how can we estimate its values using R?

Comment: Have you checked for conflicts with the function `predict`? This is loaded in `stats`, too. [Check for conflicts using `conflicts()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354697/list-of-masked-functions-in-r)

Comment: I believe that the `predict ()` function returns the values of `t` due to the organization of the model (`t = "..."`). I considered isolating `X`, but as I mentioned above, this does not seem possible.